# How to detect if a div has a scrollbar?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to determine if a div has a scrollbar and then remove that div.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I'm not able to detect it.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cyj2sb0g

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasHorizontalScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0) ? this.get(0).scrollWidth > this.innerWidth() : false;
    }
})(jQuery);

if($(".ls-boxscore").hasHorizontalScrollBar()){
    $(this).remove();
}
```

Comment: You haven't added jQuery library to jsFiddle and in `$(this).remove()` `this` points to a `window` object. What are you trying to do?

Comment: just testing to remove the div if scrollbar exists . added library , forgot

Answer (score 1):

Your `hasHorizontalScrollBar` function is working fine.

Inside `if` block `this` doesn't point to that div but to `window` object, change it to:

```
if($(".ls-boxscore").hasHorizontalScrollBar()){
    $(".ls-boxscore").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.
also you can achieve with adding `ID` to an element. using `id` you don't need to go into `element[0]`

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        var attrClass = $(this).attr("class");
        var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName(attrClass);
        return elmnt[0].scrollWidth > this.width();
    }
})(jQuery);


$(function(){
    var scrollBarFound = $('.ls-boxscore').hasScrollBar();
    if(scrollBarFound) {
        console.log('scrollbarfound');
        $('.ls-boxscore').remove();
    }
});
```